# How to use multiple encoding in the strings command of unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So based on its help :

https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings

it can use many encoding's for searching

but for example i want it to search for multiple encoding's, like "a" "b" "l" (ascii, big endian unicode, little endian unicode)

but using it like `-e a b l` OR `-e {a,b,l}` OR `-e l -e b -e` a won't work

how can i achieve this ?

also there seems to be some bugs with this command, for example some of the Unicode strings in windows PE files are found using the "l" and some are found "b" even tho the endianness of both group of strings are the same!! tried using other versions of strings but they are slow.

Comment: Isn't this a question you should have asked to maintainer(s) of the project?

Comment: As a workaround, could you do multiple runs (first `strings -e a`, then `strings -e b`, and so on) or is the order of the printed strings important?